# fullcalendar agendaDay scroll to first event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i am using fullcalendar v2.4 and i know option scrollTime can be used to scroll to have the agendaDay scroll to a certain time, like this:

```
$('#calendarday').fullCalendar({
    header: {
  },
   weekends: true, //  show Saturdays and Sundays
   defaultView: 'agendaDay',
   events: entries, 
   scrollTime: "15:00:00",
});
```

now i want to scroll to first event of the day: that means i dynamically fetch the start-time of the first event in agendaDay with jquery:

```
var firstEventTime = $("div.fc-time:first> span:nth-child(1)").text() + ":00";
```

this finds the first div "fc-time" and then selects the start time in the interior span(which is in the format H:mm ).

but it does not work to put firstEventTime into the scroll

```
$('#calendarday').fullCalendar({
    header: {
  },
   weekends: true, //  show Saturdays and Sundays
   defaultView: 'agendaDay',
   events: entries, 
   scrollTime: firstEventTime,
 });
```

is this possible at all?

Comment: If you can get the first event time without initializing fullCalendar than this should not be a problem. 

Since you are initializing the calendar you can't use it to get a value before its initialized ;)

Comment: aww, silly me,,,you are absolutely right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to scroll to the first event for a day in the agendaDay view by using the eventAfterAllRender option.

Note that this is looking at the internal elements generated by the plug-in, so if the author changes them in the next version, this approach may have to be updated.

I also took a shortcut and used the jQuery scrollTo plug-in from Ariel Flesler because I was already using it. You could achieve the same results with your own javascript if you prefer.

[jQuery scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plug-in URL

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
    if('agendaDay'===view.name){
            if($('.fc-time-grid-event').length>0){
                var renderedEvents = $('div.fc-event-container a');
                var firstEventOffsetTop = renderedEvents&&renderedEvents.length>0?renderedEvents[0].offsetTop:0;
                $('div.fc-scroller').scrollTo(firstEventOffsetTop+'px');
            }
        }            
    },
```

Comment: how would a javascript version look like? cannot get it to work with : `var target = document.getElementById("target");
            document.body.scrollTop = target.offsetTop; `

Comment: works like a charm, needed only to change `scrollTo` to `scrollTop`

Comment: This is pretty nice, but it doesn't work (for me at least) when the event goes out of view. Eg: My agenda has time ranges from 0 to 23, but starts by showing 0 to 12. If I try to scroll to hour 15, this won't work.

Comment: This code is in production and our tests do not reproduce your symptoms. It has been tested with IE (Edge - IE8), Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. However, I can create a mock-up that does demonstrate your problem in all browsers. There is a method in the FullCalendar code that gets called after events have been rendered. So, the events are rendered, the scroller is advanced to the first event, then the scroller is moved to the "scrollTime". Because it appears to be timing-related, the problem doesn't occur during ajax calls to fetch events. Not sure, but this may be a  defect in FullCalendar.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the entries array, just use the first event from that array.

```
    //First we get todays events, this is not very detailed but should work

    var events = entries;
    var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);


    events
    .filter(function (el) {  
        return el.start.split('T')[0] == today;
    })
    .sort(function(a, b) {return new Date(a.start) - new Date(b.start)});


    /*then we initialize the */

    $('#calendarday').fullCalendar({
        header: {
      },
       weekends: true, //  show Saturdays and Sundays
       defaultView: 'agendaDay',
       events: entries, 
       scrollTime: events[0].start.split('T')[1]
     });
```

Assuming your `start` time is in `2010-01-09T12:30:00` format

Comment: well, entries has all events for the whole calendar month

Comment: To get today's first event, we need to filter the events array for todays' events, Ill edit the answer to update it.

Comment: i wrote a function that calculates the first event time and the result is a string for instance `var mintime = "22:00:11"`. Putting mintime as scrollTime still does not work. So the question is whether variables are possible at all here as values for scrollTime.

Answer (score 1):

This works for week and day view:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
            if ($("#calendar .fc-event").length > 0) {
                var op = 999999;
                $("#calendar .fc-content-col").each(function(index){
                    if($(this).find('.fc-event:first').length > 0){
                        var ot = $(this).find('.fc-event:first').position().top;
                        if(ot < op){
                            op=ot;
                        }
                    }
                });
                if( op < 999999){
                    $("#calendar .fc-scroller").animate({
                        scrollTop: op
                    }, 250);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.scrollPrimerEvento = function () {
      window.setTimeout(function () {

          var renderedEvents = null;

          if (angular.element('.fc-time-grid-event').length > 0) {

              renderedEvents = angular.element('div.fc-event-container a');
              var firstEventOffsetTop = renderedEvents && renderedEvents.length > 0 ? angular.element('div.fc-event-container a').sort(function (a, b) { if (Number(angular.element(a).css('top').replace('px', '')) < Number(angular.element(b).css('top').replace('px', ''))) { return -1; } if (Number(angular.element(a).css('top').replace('px', '')) > Number(angular.element(b).css('top').replace('px', ''))) { return 1; } return 0; })[0].offsetTop - 25 : 0;

              angular.element('div.fc-scroller').animate({ scrollTop: firstEventOffsetTop }, 500);
          }

          if (angular.element('.fc-timeline-event').length > 0) {
              renderedEvents = angular.element('div.fc-event-container a');
              var firstEventOffsetLeft = renderedEvents && renderedEvents.length > 0 ? angular.element('div.fc-event-container a').sort(function (a, b) { if (Number(angular.element(a).css('left').replace('px', '')) < Number(angular.element(b).css('left').replace('px', ''))) { return -1; } if (Number(angular.element(a).css('left').replace('px', '')) > Number(angular.element(b).css('left').replace('px', ''))) { return 1; } return 0; })[0].offsetLeft - 25 : 0;

              angular.element(angular.element('div.fc-scroller')[3]).animate({ scrollLeft: firstEventOffsetLeft }, 500);
          }

      }, 1000);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar 3.2.0

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
        if("agendaDay"===view.name){
            if($(".fc-event").length>0){
                var firstEvent = $(".fc-event:first");
                view.hardSetScroll({top:firstEvent.offset().top});
            }
        }          
    }
```